# Drawing circle on OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, drawing, geometry, orthographic

This code is supposed to just draw a circle on a window, but the circle doesn't show up.  I'm using the function `glVertex2f`.

```
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <math.h>

void init(void) {
    glClearColor(0.686, 0.933, 0.933,0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0,200.0,0.0,150.0);
}
void lineSegment(void) {
    float theta;
    int posX = 400;
    int posY = 400;
    int radio = 100;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.4,0.2);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for(int i=0; i<360; i++){
        theta = i*3.1416/180;
        glVertex2f(posX + radio*cos(theta), posY + radio*sin(theta));
    }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50,50);
    glutInitWindowSize(800,800);
    glutCreateWindow("Cerámica Ana");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(lineSegment);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Hi Ana!  What have you tried so far to debug this?

Comment: @MaxvonHippel She would have to debug the GPU!

Comment: Fair point.  But debugging might mean in that case trying a different gpu, to rule out the possibility of individual hardware peculiarities, right?

Answer (score 3):

You have setup an orthographic projection:

```
gluOrtho2D(0.0,200.0,0.0,150.0);
```

The geometry within the rectangle, which is defined by the orthographic projection, is projected on the viewport. This means, that the geometry with coordinates form (0,0) to (200, 150) is visible on the viewport. The geometry out of this area is clipped.

But the center of the circle is at (500, 500) and is radius is 100. So it is not inside the clipping region.

Since the size of the viewport is (800, 800), I reommeend to adapt the orthgraphic projection to the viewport.
See [`gluOrtho2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluOrtho2D.xml) and [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml).

Change the orthographic projection to solve the issue:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
gluOrtho2D(0.0, 800.0, 0.0, 800.0);
```